# Returning cards to their owner's hands in MTG

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I have two cards that say "Return two target creatures to their owner's hands," but there is no target location from where those cards may be. So could I recover two creatures from exile, and put them into my hand? What about my graveyard?

For reference, those cards are [Floodwaters](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=426755) and [Grasping Current](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=435443).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A "creature" by definition means a permanent on the battlefield.

> 109.2 If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

So whenever something says "Target creature", it always is referring to the battlefield.

Whenever a spell wants to refer to a card in another zone, such as the graveyard, it will use the phrase "creature card" or "creature spell". See [Reanimate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bReanimate%5d) as an example.

Worth noting that there is another, somewhat redundant rule, dealing with targeting specifically:

> 114.2 Only permanents are legal targets for spells and abilities, unless a spell or ability (a) specifies that it can target an object in another zone or a player, (b) targets an object that can't exist on the battlefield, such as a spell or ability, or (c) targets a zone.

This rule clarifies that if the spell isn't specific about targeting something in another zone, etc, then it can only target permanents.

> 110.1. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield.